# Do you find sugar cane near water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

One day I needed paper and I turned all of my sugar cane into sugar.  So, I wondered do you find sugar cane near water?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sugar cane is found naturally near water.  https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sugar_cane